# Windows App SDK 1.2: How to prevent the application from shutdown when the main window is closed?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-app-sdk

I am building a Windows App SDK app that needs to stay alive and display a tray icon when the main window is closed.

For WPF, I know this can be achieved by setting `ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"`. And I wonder how can I do this with Windows App SDK 1.2.

Appreciate any useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. [AppWindow.Hide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.appwindow.hide?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2)

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();


        IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
        WindowId windowId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
        AppWindow appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);

            
        Closed +=  (s, e) =>
        {                      
            e.Handled = true;
            appWindow.Hide();                 
                
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

Hook class `AppWindow`'s `Closing` event and set `AppWindowClosingEventArgs.Cancel = true` to prevent the window from closing. Then, call `window.Hide()` to hide the window.